# How to get second derivative of state as a output of state-space model?

Tags: state-space

Let's say modeling the free-falling object on state-space.
Obviously, the equation of motion is a second order differential equation of the vertical position of the object.
And one would normally set vertical position "x" and its derivative "x dot" as element of state to configure a state-space model.
However, the output is only a linear combination of states(and input).
In this case what would be the best option to get "acceleration" or second derivative "x double dot" as an output?

This is quite a basic question, but can't find a good example.

Edit)
Consider a falling ball with vertical force F and positional sensor y. How can I represent an additional acceleration sensor "y_2" on the model below?

$$\begin{matrix} \dot{x} \\ \ddot{x} \end{matrix} = \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} *\begin{matrix} x \\ \dot{x} \end{matrix} + \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1/m & -1 \end{matrix}*\begin{matrix} F \\ g\end{matrix}$$
$$\begin{matrix} y \end{matrix} = \begin{matrix} 1& 0 \end{matrix}*\begin{matrix} x \\\dot{x} \end{matrix} + 0 *\begin{matrix} F \\ g\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Are you just asking about \$F-m\ddot{x}=0\$ or \$g-\ddot{x}=0\$?

Comment: The derivative is a linear operator. If you take the Laplace transform, you need only multiply X(s) by s^2 to obtain the Laplace transform of x double dot. If you keep things in the time domain, then just use the derivative operator on x dot (d/dt).

Comment: In this particular example, the second derivative of position is given by the original differential equation itself. Adjust the C matrix and the D matrix so that one row of the output equation replicates the original differential equation.

Comment: In a general case apply a double derivative on the position state or a single derivative on the velocity state as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @jonk I am interested in both case, but the former seems more general. So, I would say the former. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @LetterSized I would like to stay on the time domain. So, If I want to attach an accelerometer on the free-falling ball with some disturbance force, what would be my C matrix? should I expand the state vector? Hard to understand "use the derivative operator on x dot" on A, B, C, D state-space model.

Comment: @AJN Could you explain a bit more about the way how "applying a double derivative" could be done on A, B, C, D state-space model?

Comment: @Chanw Not sure what you want. But if:$$\ddot{x}=g$$Then two state vars:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1&=&x&&&&\dot{x_1}&=&\dot{x}&=&x_2\\x_2&=&\dot{x}&&&&\dot{x_2}&=&\ddot{x}\end{array}\right.$$ So:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\dot{x_1}&=&x_2\\\dot{x_2}&=&g\end{array}\right.$$State and input matrices:$$\begin{array}{c}
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\dot{x_1}\\\\\dot{x_2}
\end{smallmatrix}\right]&=&\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1\\\\0 & 0
\end{smallmatrix}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x_1\\\\x_2
\end{smallmatrix}\right]+\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0\\\\g
\end{smallmatrix}\right]
\end{array}$$

Comment: @ChanwooAhn Like that??? (Admittedly, that's going to have increasing \$x\$ in the down direction.) You have to decide the output function(s), yet. The above is A and B, but to get C and D you need the rest.

Comment: @jonk Thank you for your kind interest in my question. Could you please check the edited question?

Comment: @ChanwooAhn Well, don't assume I'm interested just yet. I may be when I feel I understand what might help you. I don't feel that way, just yet. It actually sounds more like what you want is Kalman (discrete time) or Kalman-Bucy (continuous time.) The moment you start talking about fusing information from multiple sensors, the subject has in my mind changed.

Answer (score 1):

An **ideal** acceleration sensor can be modeled using the original equation itself.

$$
a = Cx+ Du =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
\dot{x}
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
1/m & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
F\\g
\end{pmatrix}
$$

*Attach* the above `C` and `D` matrices as the second row of the corresponding matrices in your original output equation. The original output equation represented an ideal position sensor. Now the *augmented* output equation represents a position sensor (Ist row) and an acceleration sensor (IInd row).

$$
y_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
y\\
a\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
\dot{x}
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1/m & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
F\\g
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The above is for an ideal sensor. If you want to estimate the acceleration, you may need an estimator which uses the measured states and the inputs and outputs an estimate. If you want to model a non ideal sensor, you will need the above equations as well as additional states and  inputs to model the bandwidth, bias, noise etc. of the non ideal sensor.

Comment: For any higher derivatives, see [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/521665/238590) (written by me).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a very clear explanation. I’ll follow your advice.

Comment: Can you give me a bit more advice about a similar problem?   
What if one does not have a sensor for the acceleration, but needs to estimate it? If that is one of the states, then one could get it from Kalman observer of something like that, However, in this case, the acceleration is not one of the states. What could be done in this case? 

Should one just use the Kalman filter to get states and combine them with known inputs to get acceleration? Let's say there are two forces F1, the known input, and F2, the unknown but significant disturbance. What would be the right way to get the value?

Comment: Consider asking a new question. I am not so familiar with Kalman filters to give a good answer.